# How to create a custom filter in CiviCRM manage event page?

Tags: civievent, drupal

[image]

How can I add a custom field (stored as a field in Drupal db) under Manage
 Events page ,which will be displayed as dropdown.
Event Status with values **Pending** or **Approved**.

How can I alter the filters added as seen in the image?

Answer (score 3):

I would create replica of Manage event using Drupal views with same columns and filters as of Manage event screen.

If you still want to use the same screen then use pageRun hook to manipulate results by generating query and creating results and assigning to template

```
$page->assign('rows', $manageEvent);
```

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: But I want to have all the links Configure, Participants, etc  present in event items and also want to have it on the Manage Events Page, is it not preferable to 1) add a custom select list above 2) alter query ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, thanks for your invaluable help,but my main question is how I can add custom filter, would request you to provide a link or suitable answer for the same.

Comment: Hi for #2 in the above comment , I have added new question here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28248/how-to-alter-a-query-in-hook-civicrm-pagerun-based-on-a-custom-filter-provided

Answer (score 2):

Use [buildform](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook provided by civi in order to add a custom input field on the form. Use this field as a filter eg Event Status.

From the value that is posted from this form(`$_POST['event_status']`) - filter the result as mentioned by Pradeep using pageRun hook

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot!, I used $form->addElement to create custom input field and was succesful, but having some issues altering $row in hook_pageRun based on event_status value.

Comment: I tried add using `$form->addElement` in the `buildForm` hook for `CRM_Member_Form_Search` formName (Search membership), but it doesn't show up.  
It would be really useful to be able to add a custom filter. Does anyone know how to do this?