# How to alter a query in hook_civicrm_pageRun based on a custom filter provided?

Tags: civievent, hooks

I want to alter the query run in the hook_pageRun(&$page)  under Manage 
Events Page to alter the (event list) results shown here. I can alter
 the rows from hook_civicrm_pageRun , but I want to make changes 
in that row based on the values entered in the 
custom filter (e.g. default filter available is Event Type) 

Suppose I change the Event Status(custom filter) , I want to change the results of $row 
based on that filter.

Comment: Don't you get the filled values in $_POST?

Comment: okay @jitendra-fuzion, I think that should be helpful, will try ,can you answer this if possible :- https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28241/how-to-create-a-custom-filter-in-civicrm-manage-event-page?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi @jitendra-fuzion, I tried but I get an empty array when I try to print $_POST under hook_civicrm_pageRun but I see values in the session under $_SESSION['CiviCRM']['_CRM_Event_Form_SearchEvent_5dae5c805b43bf196335d884396c9c3b_9134_container']['values']['SearchEvent']['event_status']